# How can I appear and disappear a container GameObject with Text using my GameObject.activeSelf property?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, if-statement

I want to disappear a container with my `GameObject.activeSelf` is false and make it appear if it's true, how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: This? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html  works also on containers and makes all child objects also disappear...

Answer (score -1):

Assign a script to your game object and use `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` function to change other one `activeSelf`. ([Read Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html))